# Removing html entities in parsed text - Php

Tags: php, html-entities

How  to remove/convert characters  like this "â€™" from parsed HTML Text?

Whether there is any function to remove this??

Comment: What character set are you using / observing these characters in?

Comment: Is this data received from a form field `POST`ed to your php app? More detail on the source of the "parsed HTML" and what you're trying to do with it would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using html_entity_decode or a similar PHP function check if there's a parameter to define the character set used for example.

```
html_entity_decode ( string $string [, int $quote_style = ENT_COMPAT [, string $charset = 'UTF-8' ]] )
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

UTF-8 will PROBABLY display characters correctly assuming the source isn't weird.

Answer (score 0):

Those characters are normally do to the encoding your browser is interpreting the page with.
You could try changing the encoding with a meta tag in the `<head>` like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```